# Why were there painted black rings on the SRBs?

Tags: space-shuttle, srb

There were black rings on the STS-1 SRBs.

[image]

There were even more on later flights.

[image]

But there was a period without them at all.

[image]

Why?

Comment: They're called go-faster rings, very popular in the 80s' ;)

Comment: Here is a reference (from the modelling world) of the different markings by mission (not secure): http://axmpaperspacescalemodels.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/ET-SRB-External-Markings.pdf

Comment: Nice picture of Challenger and the worm logo. The first picture also reminds me that the launch tower stayed red in the simulator visuals throughout the program.

Comment: I think the thin black rings are high temp/shear rubber (SF-EPDM) stiffener rings to help absorb water impact.

Comment: @aml with a reference, that could be an excellent answer. (I don't think it's right, but I could be wrong.)